# React/React-spring: how to get an element/component out of the html flow?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-spring

I'm new to web dev (and very new to React) and I was wondering how you could get an element or component out of flow using react-spring.

Example code:

```
import React from "react";
import Hello from "./Hello"
import World from "./World"

function App() {
    return <div><Hello /><World /></div>
}

export default App;
```

```
import React from "react";
import {useSpring, animated} from "react-spring";

function Hello() {

    const props = useSpring({
        opacity: 0,
        delay: 500,
        from: {opacity: 1}
    })

    return <animated.h1 style={props}>Hello</animated.h1>
}

export default Hello;
```

```
import React from "react";
import {useSpring, animated} from "react-spring";

function World() {

    const props = useSpring({
        opacity: 1,
        delay: 1000,
        from: {opacity: 0}
    })

    return <animated.h1 style={props}>World</animated.h1>
}

export default World;
```

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve here is have *Hello* disappear and then have *World* appear **in the same spot**. But because opacity does nothing but makes the element transparent, *World* appears in the next line. So, I was wondering if there was any way to make the element go in and out of flow using simple code.

End goal -
[Hello](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSRz9.png)
[world](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6gnC.png)

1. Have *Hello* disappear and then go out of flow
2. Have *World* introduced into the flow and reappear

Comment: I dont use React-spring but if you want to take an element out of the flow then you have to use "display:none".